# Calculating summation over months of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe given below:

```
ID       Year       R1  R1_f
KAR1    20201001    1   5
KAR1    20201101    2   6
KAR1    20201201    3   7
KAR1    20210101    4   8
KAR1    20210201    5   9
KAR1    20210301    6   10
KAR1    20210401    7   11
KAR1    20210501    8   12
KAR1    20210601    9   13
KAR1    20210701    10  14
KAR1    20210801    11  15
KAR1    20210901    12  16
KAR2    20201001    4   9
KAR2    20201101    3   8
KAR2    20201201    2   7
KAR2    20210101    1   6
KAR2    20210201    9   5
KAR2    20210301    2   4
KAR2    20210401    6   3
KAR2    20210501    5   2
KAR2    20210601    3   1
KAR2    20210701    30  2
KAR2    20210801    34  3
KAR2    20210901    20  4
```

I need to transform above dataframe as given below:

```
    ID Year      R1_sum 3m_R1 6m_R1 9m_R1 12m_R1 R1_f 3m_R1_f 6m_R1_f 9m_R1_f 12m_R1_f 
   KAR1 20210901   12      33    57    72    78    16    45     81      108      126 
   KAR2 20210901   20      84    98    110   119    4     9      15      30        54
```

In above output dataframe:

R1_sum is having value equal to value in year 20210901 for both Id's.

3m_R1 is the summation of values of 3 months 20210901 to 20210701 for column R1

6m_R1 is the summation of values of 6 months from 20210901 to 20210401 for column R1

9m_R1 is the summation of values of 9 months from 20210901 to 20210101 for column R1

12m_R1 is the summation of values of 12 months from 20210901 to 20201001 for column R1

R1_f is having value equal to value in year 20210901 for both Id's.

3m_R1_f is the summation of values of 3 months 20210901 to 20210701 for column R1_f

6m_R1_f is the summation of values of 6 months from 20210901 to 20210401 for column R1_f

9m_R1_f is the summation of values of 9 months from 20210901 to 20210101 for column R1_f

12m_R1_f is the summation of values of 12 months from 20210901 to 20201001 for column R1_f

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For count from last months to first months per groups `ID` first crate helper groups by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and aggregate `sum`, then aggregate `sum` with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), flatten `MultiIndex in columns` and add to DataFrame created by [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 
                          'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR1', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2', 'KAR2'], 
                   'Year': [20201001, 20201101, 20201201, 20210101, 20210201, 20210301,
                            20210401, 20210501, 20210601, 20210701, 20210801, 20210901, 
                            20201001, 20201101, 20201201, 20210101, 20210201, 20210301,
                            20210401, 20210501, 20210601, 20210701, 20210801, 20210901], 
                   'R1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 30, 34, 20], 
                   'R1_f': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
    
print (df)
```

---

```
cols = ['R1','R1_f']
g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False) // 3
df1 = df.groupby(['ID',g])[cols].sum().groupby(level=0).cumsum().unstack()
print (df1)
      R1               R1_f              
       0   1    2    3    0   1    2    3
ID                                       
KAR1  33  57   72   78   45  81  108  126
KAR2  84  98  110  119    9  15   30   54

df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['Year'] + cols].last()
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, [-1]])
print (df2)
            -1  -1   -1
ID                     
KAR1  20210901  12   16
KAR2  20210901  20    4

df = df2.join(df1).sort_index(axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum'))
print (df)
     ID      Year  R1_sum  3m_R1  6m_R1  9m_R1  12m_R1  R1_f_sum  3m_R1_f  \
0  KAR1  20210901      12     33     57     72      78        16       45   
1  KAR2  20210901      20     84     98    110     119         4        9   

   6m_R1_f  9m_R1_f  12m_R1_f  
0       81      108       126  
1       15       30        54
```

Comment: Can you please suggest way to do it in single code instead of merging

Comment: @Python_help - Not understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: Here I have given 2 columns R1 and R1_f in actual data set I have around 20 such columns so if I have to incorporate your code for actual dataset any changes if you want to suggest.

Comment: @Python_help - Answer was edited.

Comment: @Python_help - I miss it, aded to answer.

Comment: On adding this line df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['Year'] + cols].last() I'm getting keyerror columns not found can you please help in it. Year is of type int64

Comment: @Python_help - So it means in `print (df.columns)` is not `Year` column?

Comment: yeah it's not date type column it's of type int64

Comment: yes, it is correct, what is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: @Python_help - error mean not column `Year` in original DataFrame. So ask for `print (df.columns)`

Comment: print(df.columns) gave list of column present in df and in end dtype = object is written

Comment: @Python_help - I know it, but no idea what return in your DataFrame.

Comment: can you please elaborate what you mean by return in your dataframe I can check it for you does year column needs to be of datetime format?

Comment: I expected for `print (df.columns)` you write `Index(['ID', 'Year', 'R1', 'R1_f'], dtype='object')`, but in your real data ouput is different, because error

Comment: print(df.columns) is giving similar output only which you mentioned

Comment: @Python_help - If not write exact what return `print (df.columns)` then no idea why `error mean not column Year`

Comment: print (df.columns) is giving Index(['ID', 'Year', 'R1', 'R1_f'], dtype='object') looks like your code is not able to take Year column in line df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['Year'] + cols].last() as cols list contains list of column given as string is it due to that. If possible can you please split line df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['Year'] + cols].last() at +cols stage and try to check at your end

Comment: @Python_help - weird, if check `print (df2)` in answer there is correct column `Year`.

Comment: @Python_help - maybe some wronf assign, if check `print (df.columns)` in line before `df2 = df.groupby('ID')[['Year'] + cols].last()` it is still `Index(['ID', 'Year', 'R1', 'R1_f'], dtype='object')` ?

Comment: yes print(df.columns) is giving the same output Index(['ID', 'Year', 'R1', 'R1_f'], dtype='object') can you please let what dtype you have considered for column Year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245217/discussion-between-python-help-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Python_help - are data confidental? 
f not, is possible hare them in csv by gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer...?

Comment: yes data can't transferred into csv due to confidentiality I wanted to know in previous solution where you did not involved Year but still you got r1_sum as 12 and 20 corresponding to 202109 how is that possible if we don't put Year into code

Comment: @Python_help - added data to answer used for my solution. Can you try it if solution working with this data for you?

Comment: I updated Year column as per given in actual data can you please check if your logic is working fine with updated year column

Comment: @Python_help - Working well.

Comment: can you please check your code now with updated data actually ID has KAR infront of it and it's of type object in actual data

Comment: @Python_help - added new data to answer, working well.

Comment: I was able to resolve previous error but now when I'm running I'm getting error on df.pop('Year_sum') why are we popping when we don't have any such column and since I 16 columns in my actual dataframe does this line needs to be changed - df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]  ?

Comment: @Python_help - |If remove `df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum'))` it working? What is if remove it - `print (df.columns[-1])` - name of last column?

Comment: in my solution it is `Year_sum`

Comment: `df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum'))` - this code take last column `Year_sum`, remove it by `pop` and create new second column `Year` by insert function

Comment: Id             Year                        R1                                   R1_f       
                             -1                     -1      0     1     2     3           -1      0     1     2       3
0         KAR1        202109             12     33   57   72  78           16   45   81    108   126
If I dont include df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum')) it is giving multiindex dataframe like given above

Comment: @Python_help - not understand. why remove `df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]` ?

Comment: I removed line df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum')) not line df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]   I'm getting multiindex dataframe not the one which you gave in output

Comment: @Python_help - super. `it is giving multiindex dataframe like given above`  Not understand. Because `df = df.reset_index()` removed MultiIndex in rows, `df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]` remove MultiIndex in columns. So how possible MultiIndex in `df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum')) ` ?

Comment: I'm not able to understand in which step your creating Year_sum column may be that is where my data is giving issue can you please explain in which step year_sum column is getting created so I can check

Comment: @Python_help - If remove `df.insert(1, 'Year', df.pop('Year_sum'))` it working? What is if remove it - `print (df.columns[-1])` - name of last column?

Comment: When I'm printing df2 I'm getting Year R1 and R1_f as columns with corresponding index -1, -1, -1  but I think your not getting Year column in df2?

Comment: I'm getting column names R1 and R1_f with index below them as -1,0,1,2,3 where -1 contains value of month 202109,0 contains value of last 3 months,1 contains value of last 6 months,2 contains values of last 9 months, 3 contains value of last 12 months similarly for column R1_f  but not as output given by you which contains column names as  R1_sum  3m_R1  6m_R1  9m_R1  12m_R1 and their corresponding months values

Comment: @Python_help not understand. Do you use same dataframes names like df, df1, df2, df? Because not idea what is problem. For me working code perfectly.

Comment: I was to resolve issue, issue was in this line df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns]  I changed it to y = df.columns = [f'{(b + 1) * 3}m_{a}' if b!=-1 else f'{a}_sum' for a, b in df.columns] and df.columns = y and I worked and thanks a-lot for your code and all your support