# I have data in two columns in a pandas dataframe. One is a column of months which can repeat, the other column has purchases. Need a total per mo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

How would I extract data from this dataframe so that I can see the total expenditures per month and also show a bar chart of expenditures per month.

```
Month Column      Expenditures Column        Type Column
Jan               3.19                       Food
Jan               7.18                       Travel
Feb               15.55                      Food
Mar               11.87                      Entertainment
Mar               12.88                      Food
etc.....
```

Also want to show totals by type by month.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446219/calculating-summation-over-months-of-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

To show total expenditure by month use:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Month Column')['Expenditure Column'].sum().reset_index()
print(df2)
```

which prints:

```
  Month Column  Expenditure Column
0          Feb               15.55
1          Jan               10.37
2          Mar               24.75
```

To plot this out as a bar chart use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(df2['Month Column'], df2['Expenditure Column'])
plt.show()
```

To show monthly expediture by type use:

```
df3 = df.groupby(['Month Column', 'Type Column'])['Expenditure Column'].sum().reset_index()
print(df3)
```

which prints:

```
 Month Column    Type Column  Expenditure Column
0          Feb           Food               15.55
1          Jan           Food                3.19
2          Jan         Travel                7.18
3          Mar  Entertainment               11.87
4          Mar           Food               12.88
```